# Combination of \pm and \EUR

Tags: symbols, eurosym

I am trying to simply combine a Euro sign with the plus-minus symbol \pm. However the Euro sign is always converted to a small e, instead of the actual €. Is there a simply workaround? 
Thanks!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{eurosym} 

\begin{document}

\pm \EUR{1} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\pm` is a math mode symbol, thus TeX generates an error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
```

and switches to math mode as error recovery:

```
? h
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
```

but `\EUR` does not work well in math mode, because it sets the text font, but uses the current (math) font for the symbol (`\officialeuro`).

It works, if `\pm` is correctly set in math mode without covering `\EUR`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{eurosym}

\begin{document}

$\pm$\EUR{1}  

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Euro in math mode

`\officialeuro` can also be patched that it can be used in math mode:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{eurosym}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\expandafter\pretocmd\csname officialeuro \endcsname{\nfss@text}{}{%
  \errmessage{Patching \@backslashchar officialeuro failed}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\pm \EUR{1}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Alternative to Heiko's answer:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{eurosym} 

\begin{document}

$\pm \textrm{\EUR{1}}$

\end{document}
```